# Group of Regular expression matches, return nth match and assign to array

Tags: regex, perl

```
$content = "<p><strong>haha</p> .. .. .. <p><strong> hihi </p>";
my @eachTopic = ($content =~ /(<p><strong>)(.*?)(<\/p>)/g);
#I only want to capture the $2 and add it to array

print $_."\n" foreach(@eachTopic);
```

The resulting array should have 2 values  $eachTopic[0] = "haha" and $eachTopic[1] = "hihi".

I know i could do this using for loop and using a if statement, but just wondering, is there  anything in regular expression that i can do something like

```
@arr = ($content =~ /(x)(.*?)(x)/g$2/)
```

Comment: You are clearly unfamiliar with Perl. Had you considered using a proper HTML parser? [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder) is excellent, and [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath) allows you to address the HTML document using XPath phrases. If you would like to show your data in context then I can write a useful answer.

Comment: If it's not HTML then what is it? No one can help you unless you explain your problem properly. Do you have an XML document, or something different altogether?

Comment: I've had to flag your question for closure because it is unclear what you are asking. I am more than happy to help you, but no one can give good advice without more information about the real situation.

Comment: BTW, I encountered this question in a close votes review, and it now has 4 close votes, but I disagree. The phrasing may be awkward, but by providing sample input and expected results, he makes it perfectly clear what he's trying to accomplish. That's why we always tell people to provide examples, precisely because trying to describe things in words is often vague and ambiguous. So, it wouldn't make sense to close a question where someone has done exactly that just because the wording is unclear. The question as a whole should be clear to anyone who looks at the sample input and desired result

Comment: Nominating for reopening. What he's asking is clear as spring water.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do this with a match group, use zero-width assertions to match what comes before and after the part you want to match. That way you're matching only that part, and a global match will return an array of all occurences.

```
my @eachTopic = ($content =~ /(?<=<p><strong>).*?(?=<\/p>)/g);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried split?

like so:

```
my @topics = map{  $_ =~ s/<\/p>$//; $_ }split( /<p><strong>/, $txt );
```

This of course fails if your string contains something other than `<p><strong>...</p>` at some point...

Comment: Neither XML nor HTML should be processed using anything other than a tested and reliable parser module.

Comment: HTML:: TreeBuilder is great. However, it can be split! If it can be split, all is good.

Comment: The questions has tags, doesnot mean we're parsing HTML tags. This is a generic question. I made it simpler to make it look like a html syntax.

Comment: @bytepusher This doesnt work in this case as well. That "... ..." means there is a whole bunch of log file data in that and it follows after and before as well.

Comment: @bytepusher: No, all is not good. All it takes is an unusual pattern in the input data for things to start going awry. I tried to explain in my comment on a previous answer of yours that providing working code for the OP should be very low on your list of priorities. Even in this situation it is extraordinarily poor advice to recommend a simple text-based solution, but sympathise witrh all the other people who will come along and take your advice to use `split` to process HTML as *the way* to do it.

Comment: Then why are you regexping it? You really should use a decent parser. HTML::TreeBuilder is very nice for the job. use the <p><strong> to find the right ones, as_text to get the text only.

Comment: @bytepusher: LOL! About face!

Comment: @Mithun: If it's not HTML then what is it? No one can help you unless you explain your problem properly. Do you have an XML document, or something different altogether?

Comment: Well, I could not resist throwing in a split. But it should honestly be said that you are right to parse HTML, one should use it. I would, too, and have, whenever HTML comes my way

Comment: @bytepusher: You *must always* resist "throwing in a `split`". It is appalling advice.

Comment: Throwing in resist I will. And still, map and split - always a fit!

Comment: @bytepusher: You seriously worry me, as you have a habit of offering an answer in the terms that the questioner wants to hear, regardless of whether it is good advice. I can see from your code that you are not an experienced Perl programmer. Please back off and learn a lot more before you drag others down the wrong path.